# How to Create 2D Array with #1 in Random Positions for Specific Number of Times

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create an 8x8 array with JAVA, in which i want to have 1 eight times in random generated positions. All the other positions of the array are going to be 0. I am using this code but obviously it is not filling the array with 1 for a specific number of times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [][] arr = new int [8][8];

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            arr[i][j] =  (int) (Math.random()*2);
        }
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
        for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++){
            System.out.print(arr[k][l] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
import java.util.Random;

int[][] array = new int[8][8];
Random r = new Random();

int a = r.nextInt(8);
int b = r.nextInt(8);

//insert 8 random 1's in the 8x8 matrix, no duplicates
//by default in Java the other places are 
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    while(array[a][b] == 1){
        a = r.nextInt(8);
        b = r.nextInt(8);
    }
    array[a][b] = 1;
}
```